# Racket syntax error using 'let star'

Tags: syntax, racket, let

In the program listed below, I'm getting the error message:

let*: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: pokemon1inPokedex

I'm not sure why, any advice would be appreciated!

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghSaj.png)

```
(define (in-order? pokemon1name pokemon2name)
  (let*
    [pokemon1inPokedex (inPokedex? pokemon1name)]
    [pokemon2inPokedex (inPokedex? pokemon2name)])
  (cond [(and pokemon1inPokedex pokemon2inPokedex) (greater pokemon1name pokemon2name)]
        [(true? pokemon1inPokedex) #t]
        [(true? pokemon2inPokedex) #f]
        [else #f]))
```

Comment: Did you forget to choose a non-teaching language in DrRacket?

Comment: Please insert the code as text in your post, not as image.

Comment: Which language do you use? Eg does it say `#lang racket` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have incorrect syntax with `let*`.

From the racket guide, the syntax for [`let*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html?q=let*#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%2A%29%29) is

```
(let* ([id val-expr] ...) body ...+)
```

Note the missing `(` and `)` parens for the identifiers you are binding, as well as your moved closing `)`.

Modifying your example to use the the `let*` form correctly will result in code that looks something like:

```
(define (in-order? pokemon1name pokemon2name)
  (let* ([pokemon1inPokedex ...]
         [pokemon2inPokedex ...])
    (cond [(and pokemon1inPokedex) ...]
          [pokemon1inPokedex ...]
          [pokemon2inPokedex ...]
          [else ...]))
```

Obviously I've left the `...` for you to fill in.

As a side note, `pokemon1inPokedex` doesn't really follow any normal Racket naming convention that I am aware of. Following [standard naming conventions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Textual_Matters.html?q=style%20guide) in Racket would give you `pokemon1-in-pokedex?`